# Chrome filter out SameSite:None secure cookie

Tags: google-chrome, samesite

We have web application with an iFrame, which needs a cookie to access our server.  We have set this cookie with SameSite=None;Secure value, but the Chrome browser still filter out this cookie.

Filtered out cookie list:

[image: filtered out cookie list]

The third cookie in this picture is filtered out.  I thought cookies with "SameSite=None;Secure" should be send with request.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me to see if your browser is enforcing the new defaults. If it's all green ✔, then it is. If there is any red or orange ✘ then something is affecting how cookies are set.

Check you do not have the setting enabled to block third-party cookies, e.g. go to `chrome://settings/content/cookies` and ensure "Block third-party cookies" is off.

Extensions may also affect cookies. Try testing in an incognito window or a fresh Chrome profile with no extensions installed.

Comment: Our chrome browsers has company controlled settings.  I found out "Blocking third-party cookies" is set to on.  Once I turned it off, the cookie is sent.
This setting is also present in Microsoft edge browser.